# finding Human dimensions from photos

Tags: image-processing, object-detection

I'm working on a problem where I have to extract different human parts real-world dimensions ( waist width, arm length ) from photos where there are front and side photos,
the given values are the camera specifications, the person's real-world height and their distance from the camera.

right now I am able to figure out the dimensions of the different parts in pixels, but I couldn't find a method to translate them to real-world measures. 
[image: front view]
[image: side view]
are there accurate methods to achieve this?

thank you for the help.

Comment: Could you post examples of your pictures? If they are taken in the same circumstances, then there is only one scaling coefficient.

Comment: @DimaMironov there are two images, front, and side. 
the user will be 160cm away from the camera.
the camera is about 90 degrees and held by the wall.